# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" received when using NSFileManager to retrieve multiple values

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsfilemanager

I receive the following error when I attempt to retrieve multiple values using NSFileManager: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is my code:

```
class func loadGameData() -> (HighScore: Int, HasCompletedTutorial: Bool) {
    // getting path to GameData.plist
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as! String
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("GameData.plist")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    //check if file exists
    if(!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {
        // If it doesn't, copy it from the default file in the Bundle
        if let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GameData", ofType: "plist") {
            let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
            fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath: path, error: nil)
        }
    }

    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

    if let dict = myDict {
        //loading values - THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        let HighScore: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("HighScore")!
        let CompletedTutorial: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("HasCompletedTutorial")! 

        return (Int(HighScore as! NSNumber), Bool(CompletedTutorial as! NSNumber))
    }

    return (0, false)
}
```

I have tested both of the lines by themselves, and they work perfectly. But they don't seem to work together

Here is the code used to call the function

```
let val = GameData.loadGameData()
println(val.HighScore)
println(val.HasCompletedTutorial)
```

I have tested multiple variants of this function call and it has not made a difference

Thank You

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?  Is 'paths' nil?

Comment: @RehcsifMit the error happens on these two lines: `let HighScore: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("HighScore")!
        let CompletedTutorial: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("HasCompletedTutorial")! `

Comment: Unless your dictionary is guaranteed to have those keys in it, you're better off using the '?' unwrapper and checking for nil explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you unwrap them? Try something like this

```
if let dict = myDict {
    if let 
      highScore = dict.objectForKey("HighScore"), 
      completedTutorial = dict.objectForKey("HasCompletedTutorial") 
    {
        return (Int(highScore as! NSNumber), Bool(completedTutorial as! NSNumber))
    }
}
```